# Feeding R a list of webpages through a CSV

Tags: r, loops

I have created a function which scrapes information and adds it to a data.frame. I want to feed this function a list of urls from a .csv but it does not seem to work when I make it as function.

```
IMDB <- function(wp){
  for (i in wp){
    raw_data <- getURL(i)
    data <- fromJSON(raw_data)
    data <- as.list(data)
    length(data)
    final_data <- do.call(rbind, data)
    Title <- final_data[c("Title"),]
    ScreenWriter <- final_data[c("Writer"),]
    Fdata <- cbind(Title,ScreenWriter)
    Authors <- rbind(Authors, Fdata) 
  }
}
```

Comment: Within your function you need to specify what you want returned. If the data frame you want returned is called "final_data" add this to your function `return(final_data)`

Comment: Thanks, this is a great help, in this instance, I want to return authors, and when I input return(Authors) it works, however I would like Authors as a dataframe with Title first, then Writer, but when I write Authors <- as.data.frame(return(Authors)) it does not work.

Comment: try `return(as.data.frame(Authors))`

Comment: Still just printing to the console, but it is working correctly!

Comment: Try saving your function to something named such as data and it should save to your global environment. `data = IMDB(wp)` that should save your output to a dataframe called  data and allow you to work with it.

Comment: Excellent, Colin you the man! All I can say is thank you!

Comment: Glad it's working, good luck with the movie database analysis.